# Javascript fill missing dates with day and 0 count in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, fill

I have an array generated through a code where I'm calculating, for each day from now to 7 days ago, the daily occurrences. Right now my code is skipping the days where there aren't occurrences, but I would like to insert those days together with a 0 count value. Here's my code:

```
var myObj;
fetch('https://blahblahblah?'+param1+param2+"FromDate"+"="+moment().subtract(7,'d').format('YYYY-MM-DD'))
.then(res=>res.json())
.then(data=>myObj= data);

var myRes= [];

myObj.forEach(function (elem) {
    var date = elem.CreatedDate.split(' ')[0];


    if (myRes[date]) {
        myRes[date] += 1;
    } else {
        myRes[date] = 1;
    }
});
```

Right now I'm getting a similar result:

```
2020-12-11: 1
2020-12-12: 2
2020-12-13: 1
2020-12-15: 2
2020-12-16: 1
```

Because on 12-10 I didn't have any value and on 12-14 neither. Given the startTime `moment().subtract(7,'d').format('YYYY-MM-DD')`

how can I output the days with 0 values like in the format below?:

```
2020-12-10: 0
2020-12-11: 1
2020-12-12: 2
2020-12-13: 1
2020-12-14: 0
2020-12-15: 2
2020-12-16: 1
```

Thank you very much

Edit: here's my obj:

```
[{Id, Var1, Var2, CreationDate},
{1, 123, Var2, 2020-12-11},
{2, 1234, Var2, 2020-12-12},
{3, 12345, Var2, 2020-12-12},
{4, 1234, Var2, 2020-12-13},
{5, 321, Var2, 2020-12-15},
{6, 3214, Var2, 2020-12-15},
{7, 5432, Var2, 2020-12-16}]
```

Comment: Can you add what you have in myObj?

Comment: updated the question with myObj

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you calculate myRes You can create an array with last 7 days date and then compare with myRes to create finalResult with the missing dates.

```js
let myRes = {
    '2020-12-11': 1,
    '2020-12-12': 2,
    '2020-12-13': 1,
    '2020-12-15': 2,
    '2020-12-16': 1,
}


const dates = [];
const NUM_OF_DAYS = 7; // get last 7 dates.

for (let i = 0; i < NUM_OF_DAYS; i++) {
  let date = moment();
  date.subtract(i, 'day');
  dates.push(date.format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
}


let finalResult = {};
dates.reverse().forEach(date => {
    if(!myRes.hasOwnProperty(date)) {
        finalResult[date] = 0;
    } else {
        finalResult[date] = myRes[date];
    }
});

console.log(finalResult);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked! But in some cases I'm not starting from 10 but from 11. How is that possible?

Comment: Can you explain? I am not sure. Can you please mention those cases so we can debug?"

Comment: Nothing, it was my issue. I need to sort the finalResult, in order to have the array starting from 7 days ago to now. How can I do that? finalResult.reverse() is not working

Comment: Is your final result am array or object?

Comment: I solved it by reverting dates once and modifying every forEach in order not to revert it every time. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Does this change work for you?

```js
var myRes= new Array(7).fill(0);
```